# UWP: Application Fault 1007 CStorageFileProxy release()

Tags: c#, uwp

My UWP app (C# and XAML) uses Windows.Storage to open and save files (StorageFolder, StorageFile, FileIO, etc). Everything works for most of my users. However, I see a handful of crash reports listing the following title and stack trace. I'm unable to reproduce the error. A code review shows nothing, and internet searches turn up zero.

**cstoragefileproxy release()**

**application_fault 00001007: application_fault**

```
windows.storage.dll
CStorageFileProxy Release() dataaccess.cpp:3817
System.Private.Interop.dll
System::Runtime::InteropServices::McgMarshal ComRelease_StdCall() McgMarshal.cs:454
System.Private.Interop.dll
System::Runtime::InteropServices::McgMarshal ComRelease() McgMarshal.cs:473
System.Private.Interop.dll
System::__ComObject Cleanup() __ComObject.cs:903
System.Private.Interop.dll
System::RCWFinalizer Finalize() __ComObject.cs:58
mrt100_app.dll
System::Runtime::__Finalizer DrainQueue() __Finalizer.cs:61
mrt100_app.dll
System::Runtime::__Finalizer ProcessFinalizers() __Finalizer.cs:41
mrt100_app.dll
FinalizerStart() finalizerhelpers.cpp:69
ntdll.dll
RtlUserThreadStart() rtlstrt.c:1162
```

All of my code is C# and XAML, and there are no unsafe code blocks. I notice the "McgMarshal" entry in the stack trace, perhaps there's a thread issue.

Can anyone shed some light on what might cause Windows.Storage.DLL to fault given the above?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately after turning to .Net native compiler crash reports for UWP applications became mostly useless as you have found out. They need to be processed with .pdb files that you get while compiling the app to get the real actionable report. Microsoft promised to make tool that would do something like that, but for all those years it hasn't. I think I've seen someone on GitHub made some tool for that though it is far from friendly (works from the console), but I don't have a link for it.